# Can't create a new module in Intellij(with Spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I have a problem with Intellij, when I want to create a new Module in my project it does not work.
On the first & second page is everything is normal. I select the openoracle jdk and select the Spring Assistang on the next page I change the IDs and the project name. And when I click on "Next" nothing happens. If I click again it says "Please select one dependency" which I can't, because I cannot see the page with the dependencies.
I have no idea how to fix this, has anybody a clue on how to approach this problem?

(Not sure if relevant: I freshly installed intellij on my new notebook, I already had intellig on my first notebook, but because auf reasons which would be too long to explain, I need to work on both. So I cloned my repository so that I can push from both notebooks. And this works without a problem. I did the same things on both noteboks but it only works on one.)
I already delete and reinstalled intellij.
looking forward to your replies!! (:

Comment: Please check idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) for errors/warnings.

Comment: I checked the idea.log:  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2  Build #IC-211.7442.40 
2021-06-15 09:35:21,711 [2303917]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.11; VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2021-06-15 09:35:21,711 [2303917]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Windows 10 
2021-06-15 09:35:21,712 [2303918]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin to blame: Spring Assistant version: 1.0.1 
2021-06-15 09:35:21,715 [2303921]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null

Comment: ther it says the Spring Assistant is to blame, I reinstalled it, but I don't know how to fix the error

Comment: Please try to disable plugin. Will it help?

Comment: yes when I disable the plugin I can create a module, but I kind of need the spring assistant to work.

Comment: The latest plugin version is compatible with 2017.2 — 2019.3.5 IDE versions. Please contact plugin vendor for updates: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant/versions/stable